# XML to XML transformation: Eliminating a specific punctuation placed outside an element

Tags: xml, xslt-2.0

Here is a code snippet from my xml file:

```
<citation citation-type="web">
<article-title>Dietary reference</article-title>. 
<publisher-name>The Academy</publisher-name>. 
<comment>Available from: 
<ext-link ext-link-type="uri">http://www.fap.com/catalog.php?</ext-link>
</comment>. 
<access-date>Accessed 2013</access-date>.
</citation>
```

I need to convert this to the following:

```
<citation citation-type="web">
<article-title>Dietary reference</article-title>. 
<publisher-name>The Academy</publisher-name>. 
<comment>Available from: 
<ext-link ext-link-type="uri">http://www.fap.com/catalog.php?</ext-link>
Accessed 2013</comment>. 
</citation>
```

The `access-date` element has to be eliminated but its content should be placed inside the`comment` element. But after I do this, the `.` after `</access-date>` is retained. Thus there are two full-stops now after `</comment>`. I am stuck at this point as `.` is outside the `access-date` element and I am not able to eliminate it. Help of any kind would be truly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Is there any variation in the input data so that some `citation` elements have only one text node with `.` and others have two `.`? Or what exactly is the problem to do e.g. `<xsl:template match="citation/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::access-date] and normalize-space() = '.']"/>`?

Comment: No there is no such variation. Its just that when I place `access-date` content inside `comment`, the full-stop after `access-date` element remains as it is not within `access-date`. And there is a full-stop after `comment` in input. This makes two `.`. I dont need `.` after `access-date` in output which is present in the input.

Comment: My aim is to move `access-date` content inside `comment` and eliminate `.` after `</access-date>` in input.

Comment: Show us the code you have, then we can suggest changes. If you use a template based approach starting with the identity transformation then the empty template I suggested in my first comment would ensure that the text node with the second dot is not copied.

Comment: I placed the `access-date` content within `comment` normally using template based approach and I was trying to eliminate the `.` after `</access-date>` using translate and string-replace functions which wont work I guess. I will try your code.

Comment: I have put the suggestion of my comment in an answer so that we can mark the problem as solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comments you simply need to add an empty template

```
<xsl:template match="citation/text()[preceding-sibling::node()[1][self::access-date] and normalize-space() = '.']"/>
```

to ensure the second text node with the dot `.` is not copied.